# Show that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory, independence

We have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$, let $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent sub-$\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal{A}$. We consider:

$\mathcal{F}:= \sigma \left ( \bigcup_{n even} \mathcal{A}_n\right )$ and $\mathcal{G}:= \sigma \left ( \bigcup_{n odd} \mathcal{A}_n\right )$

I want to show that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent.

For that I want to use a proposition and check that:

$\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent $\iff \forall F \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}) = \{\emptyset, \mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}^c, \Omega\}, \forall G \in \sigma(\mathcal{G}) = \{\emptyset, \mathcal{G}, \mathcal{G}^c, \Omega\} \implies \mathbb{P}[F \cap G] = \mathbb{P}[F] \mathbb{P} [G]$.

Now I would check for each combination the conditions hold:

Case 1: If both $F = G = \emptyset$ then the statement obviously holds since by defintion $\mathbb{P}[\emptyset] = 0$.

Case 2: If either $F$ or $G$ equals the empty set, the condition hold by the same argument.

Case 3: If both $F = G = \Omega$ the condition holds again by a similar argument.

Now the harder cases are those if I have to consider for example:

$F =  \mathcal{F}$ and $G = \mathcal{G}$. How can I proceed here?